# Getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: java, selenium

Iam trying to set the pagination Count to 50 but constantly getting a message that the Element is not Interactable  and could not be scrolled into view.

What I Tried:

Since this is a select class i tried to use Select By index,Select by Visible Text and Select by Value and is not working.
There are 3 select class i.e. when i take the xpath and search it shows 1 of 3 ... is there a way to get a unqiue xpath or the only option is to create multiple methods?
Tried adding WebDriverWait till the Element is Clickable and says that the ELement is not clickable.

Below is the code:

```
        // set pagination count -- 50
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(1500,0)");
        if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(AppXPathsConstants.paginationXpath)).size() != 0) {
            WebElement pageCountElement = getFluentWaitElementByXPath(AppXPathsConstants.paginationXpath,
                    20, driver);
        
            scrolltoBottom(driver);
            
            Select drp = new Select(pageCountElement);
                            
            drp.selectByVisibleText("50");
            

            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error : ElementNotInteractableException** this will occur when another element masked on your clicking element. please make sure you have added proper wait time in it. and please add screenshot just before clicking 50. that will give you idea why it is not receiving the click.

Please use this scroll,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", driver.findElement(contactUsLink));
```

Comment: added waits but still not clicking is there anything else i can do to achieve a click

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view had tried this earlier also

Comment: there are actually 1 of 3 select class in the html but not able to get a unique xpath is there a way to get a unique xpath or the only option is to create different methods?

Comment: you can use , select by value => selectByValue("50");

Comment: it does not work so my only option is to create different methods